# How do bind, put and return interact here?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

Given the following code

```
rollDie :: GeneratorState Int
rollDie = do generator <- get
             let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (1,6) generator
             put newGenerator
             return value
```

I know I can translate it as:

```
rollDie2 :: GeneratorState Int
rollDie2 = get >>= \generator ->let (value, newGenerator) = randomR(1,6) generator
                                in put newGenerator >> return value
```

I tested both functions with and without the `put newGenerator >>`, and they produce different results. My question is why? The `put` functions is pure, and the operator (`>>`) means that `return value` should be unaffected by prior results.

Comment: Your question as posted is difficult to understand. I'm not sure what you're asking. As an aside, your `rollDie` function can be rewritten `rollDie = state (randomR (1,6))`

Comment: Where is `GeneratorState` defined? Also, how did you "test" these functions?

Comment: I think I found your `GeneratorState` here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State

Comment: My central question was about, why would exist a difference using or not the "put newGenerator>>". I write the two functions only to show my interpretation of the do notation.

Answer (score 1):

When I test both functions *with the same initial state*, I get the same answer:

```
λ> evalState rollDie (mkStdGen 0)
6
λ> evalState rollDie2 (mkStdGen 0)
6
```

I suspect you're not using the same state for both tests. How exactly are you testing the functions?

Here's an example where the state (i.e. the random number generator) gets modified:

```
test :: GeneratorState (Int, Int)
test = do
  a <- rollDie -- modifies the state!
  b <- rollDie2 -- gets a different state
  return (a, b)

runTest :: IO ()
runTest = do
  g <- getStdGen
  let (a, b) = evalState test g
  print a
  print b
```

As you can see, when you run this you get two different answers.

```
λ> runTest
4
2
```